# jQuery popup content is showing on the page and popup isn't showing up

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, magnific-popup

I've tried the official jQuery Mobile popup and now also tried [Magnific](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) Popup plugin and the're all showing the content of the popup on my page instead of hiding it and showing it later in the modal.

index.php:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magnific.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="magnific.js"></script>

    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script src="livestamp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Like so: -->
<a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

<!-- Or like so: -->
<a href="mobile-friendly-page.html" data-mfp-src="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

<!-- Popup itself -->
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide">You may put any HTML here. This is dummy copy. It is not meant to be read. It has been placed here solely to demonstrate the look and feel of finished, typeset text. Only for show. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed.</div>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
});
});
```

For some weird reason the popups aren't showing up and instead I see it's content on `index.php`. jQuery-Mobile Popup resulted in the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Riccardo it looks like there are a few things which need fixing up here.

Firstly, you haven't included the jQuery Mobile script. If you're linking to the google hosted libraries, then you need to include:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Also, now that you're including jQuery Mobile, the latest version of the jQuery core which supports jQuery Mobile (currently) is 2.1, (you're currently linking to 3.1). On the Google Hosted library it's:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You also then need to the jQuery Mobile css page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
```

Now that you've got your libraries all loaded, we can get to the link which opens the popup. Following the jQuery Mobile demos [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/), you need to add `data-rel="popup"` into the link which opens the popup. Which makes your link:

```
<a href="#test-popup" data-rel="popup">Show inline popup</a>
```

Also, jQuery Mobile page structure dictates that content such as the link above be nested within a div with `role="main" class="ui-content"` which itself if nested within a div with `data-role="page":

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <!-- Like so: -->
        <a href="#test-popup" data-rel="popup">Show inline popup</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly the popup itself needs to have the `data-role="popup"` attribute included in the `div` tag:

```
<div id="test-popup" data-role="popup">Popup content</div>
```

Similarly to the link above, the popup `div` needs to be nested within the page `div`, but unlike the link (which is ordinary content), the popup is treated specially as it's not content which you want to see ordinarily; only when it's called, so it sits outside the "content" `div` as follows:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <!-- Like so: -->
        <a href="#test-popup" data-rel="popup">Show inline popup</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Popup itself -->
    <div id="test-popup" data-role="popup">Popup content</div>
</div>
```

So putting it all together, you should have in you index.php:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <!-- Like so: -->
        <a href="#test-popup" data-rel="popup">Show inline popup</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Popup itself -->
    <div id="test-popup" data-role="popup">Popup content</div>
</div>

</body>
```

You can also get rid of any custom javascript which you've written to show this popup as it's all within the jQuery and jQuery Mobile scripts.

Have a look again at the jQuery Mobile demos page for popups [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/) for further popup styling options.

[Here's a JSFiddle with this example all working.](http://jsfiddle.net/bj34120u) Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, Ill check it up when I get some spare time and will let you know if that works.